# Problem with port determination using spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have created 2 instances of a microservice named InfyGo_Flights. I have put a yaml file in git hub with
server.port 9004. My properties file in MS is empty apart from application name. These 2 instances have 2 diff issues:
1.First I overrode in the config itself to take server.port as 9010. But still ran on 9004. I deleted the server.port in yaml in github. But this caused it to run into error. So replaced it with 9004 again. But now it has started running on 9010. Removing the overridden property causes it to run into error.
2.Second config I created after the first one was causing issue. But despite the yaml file in cloud config it runs on default 8080 port.
application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=InfyGo_Flights
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:1111

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include
```

InfyGo_Flights.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: InfyGo_Flights
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
      suffix: .jsp      
 
  datasource:
    
    username: root
    password: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC
  jpa:
      show-sql: true
      hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        
      properties:
        hibernate:
            dialect: 

logging:
  file: Errorlog.log
  level:
    root: info
    com.infoys.ars: info
  pattern:
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] %c [%M] - %m%n"
server:
  port:9004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put a *Whitespace* between the `port` & `9004` so it get recognizable by the *yaml* file:

```
//wrong
 port:9004
//right
 port: 9004
```